# Android Connect MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

Надо подключится к MySQL в Android Studio и создать таблицу вот так я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
try{
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/qrdb";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "****";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

            String sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE items (Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20), price INT)";

            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)){

                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

                statement.executeUpdate(sqlCommand);

                Log.i("mytag","Database has been created!");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.i("mytag","Connection failed...");

            Log.i("mytag", "" + ex);
        }
```

Запускаю на эмуляторе исключений не выдает и приложение тупо закрывается. В обычном java проекте все работает. Тут наверно надо заменить localhost на что-то, но я менял на myip:port - не помогло. Сам MySQL Connector/J 8.0 установлен в проекте и все классы видны в обычном проекте все работает.

Comment: так jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/qrdb тоже не хочет

Answer (score 1):

Уже как то отвечал, отвечу еще раз

JDBC из Android очень сложно заставить работать. Есть 2 причины:

1. Это [антипаттерн](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716) (для Android)
2. Многие JDBC драйвера (MySQL в их числе) используют вызовы нативных библиотек, которые не работают под Android

Comment: Какие есть альтернативы? Мне надо удалено подключиться к любой БД из под андроида

Comment: REST: на сервере поднимаете веб сервис, который соединяется с БД и коммуницирует с Android